# Quantile curves (strange results at 0.975 quantile)

Tags: splines, quantile-regression

I want to calculate the quantile curves (0.025,0.25,0.5,0.75,0.975). The distribution of age is [image]

So I decided to work with quantile regression (nonlinear) so I run the following code

```
library(quantreg)
plot(dataExample$age,dataExample$y,xlab = "age", ylab = "y",type="n")

#' Fit first a nonlinear least-square regression
Data.nls <- nls(y ~ SSlogis(age, Asym, mid, scal), data=dataExample)
lines(0.008:19, predict(Data.nls, newdata=list(age=0.008:19)), col=1)

#' Then fit the median using nlrq
Data.nlrq <- nlrq(y ~ SSlogis(age, Asym, mid, scal), data=dataExample, tau=0.5, trace=TRUE)
lines(0.008:19, predict(Data.nlrq, newdata=list(age=0.008:19)), col=2)

#' The 1st and 3rd quartiles regressions
Data.nlrq <- nlrq(y ~ SSlogis(age, Asym, mid, scal), data=dataExample, tau=0.25, trace=TRUE)
lines(0.008:19, predict(Data.nlrq, newdata=list(age=0.008:19)), col=3)
Data.nlrq <- nlrq(y ~ SSlogis(age, Asym, mid, scal), data=dataExample, tau=0.75, trace=TRUE)
lines(0.008:19, predict(Data.nlrq, newdata=list(age=0.008:19)), col=3)

#' And finally "external envelopes" holding 95 percent of the data
Data.nlrq <- nlrq(y ~ SSlogis(age, Asym, mid, scal), data=dataExample, tau=0.025, trace=TRUE)
lines(0.008:19, predict(Data.nlrq, newdata=list(age=0.008:19)), col=4)

Data.nlrq <- nlrq(y ~ SSlogis(age, Asym, mid, scal), data=dataExample, tau=0.975, trace=TRUE)
lines(0.008:19, predict(Data.nlrq, newdata=list(age=0.008:19)), col=4)

leg <- c("least squares","median (0.5)","quartiles (0.25/0.75)",".95 band (0.025/0.975)")
legend(10, 30, legend=leg, lty=1, col=1:4)
```

But this is the results which I got (please look at the curve for 0.975 percentile curve). Any advice? Should I consider another method to calculate these quantile curves?
[image]

Here is the result of applying Restricted cubic spline and I define the knots at knots=c(0.025,0.25,0.50,0.75,0.975). The p-value for nonlinear test for 0.975 is 
not significant,P-value=0.3.

[image]

```
f1 <- Rq(y ~ rcs(age, knots=c(0.025,0.25,0.50,0.75,0.975)), x=TRUE, y=TRUE, tau=0.025, data=dataExample)
anova(f1)
f2 <- Rq(y ~ rcs(age, knots=c(0.025,0.25,0.50,0.75,0.975)), x=TRUE, y=TRUE, tau=0.25, data=dataExample)
anova(f2)
f3 <- Rq(y ~ rcs(age, knots=c(0.025,0.25,0.50,0.75,0.975)), x=TRUE, y=TRUE, tau=0.50, data=dataExample)
anova(f3)
f4 <- Rq(y ~ rcs(age, knots=c(0.025,0.25,0.50,0.75,0.975)), x=TRUE, y=TRUE, tau=0.75, data=dataExample)
anova(f4)
f5 <- Rq(y ~ rcs(age, knots=c(0.025,0.25,0.50,0.75,0.975)), x=TRUE, y=TRUE, tau=0.975, data=dataExample)
anova(f5)
plot(dataExample$age,dataExample$y,xlab="Age",ylab="y",cex=0.25)
lines(dataExample$age, predict(f1, newdata=dataExample), col=4, lwd=2)
lines(dataExample$age, predict(f2, newdata=dataExample), col=3, lwd=2)
lines(dataExample$age, predict(f3, newdata=dataExample), col=2, lwd=2)
lines(dataExample$age, predict(f4, newdata=dataExample), col=3, lwd=2)
lines(dataExample$age, predict(f5, newdata=dataExample), col=4, lwd=2)
leg <- c("median (0.5)","quartiles (0.25/0.75)",".95 band (0.025/0.975)")
legend("bottomright", legend=leg, lty=1, col=2:4)
```

Also this is the result of applying bs function (B-spline).

```
f1 <- rq(y ~ bs(age, knots=c(0.025,0.25,0.50,0.75,0.975)), tau=0.025, data=dataExample)
```

[image]

Comment: If you are sure about your data and nobody here has any better ideas then I would contact the package maintainer as this might be something malfunctioning.

Comment: Further exploration continued from [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/322181/which-bandwidth-i-should-choose/322189?noredirect=1#comment612280_322189). I like your second plot better, but if you are going to do that maybe try B-spline, with some derivative fitting and more automatic node selection.  Moreover, data transform may be better, post data so I can play with it to give you some hints. Disadvantage of spline fitting is that it is heuristic, and you may want to say something more revealing about your data.

Comment: @Carl, thanks so much for your kindness, unfortunately, the data is confidential and I can not share it. But I will do my best to simulate something close to it. I use the B-spline smoothing. Please check the result (fourth plot). What do you think about this result? I defined knots=c(0.025,0.25,0.5,0.75,0.975) as I did not know how to define the degree of freedom. Is that ok?

Comment: Try [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/B-Spline.html) as an explanation of knots. Maybe try 0 and 1 for your first and last knots, I think, if I am reading it correctly.

Comment: @Carl, could you please check this link "https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/322727/should-i-use-transformation-method-in-this-analysis". I used power normal transformation to transformed variables and you can see the new scatter plot between the transformed variables.