# Should I use Transformation method in this analysis?

Tags: data-transformation, quantiles

I want to calculate the quantile curves at 0.025,0.50,0.975 percentiles. I have one predictor variable (age with min value 0.08 and max value=19 years) with this distributions:
[image]

This is also the distribution of the dependent variable.
[image]

This is a scatter plot of Y vs age
[image]

Do you think using transformation(power normal transformation) for both age and y is a good idea before applying the spline smoothing techniques? Becuase I applied different smoothing methods but I could not find a good fit so I thought maybe I could have a better results by working on transformed variables. The problem here is since age includes value less than "1" the transformed age includes the negative numbers.
[image]

This is the results of applying Restricted cubic spline on original scales.
[image]

And these are the results of applying quantile regression (polynomial with degree 2 and 3).
[image]
[image]

To see the results of applying different methods (spline) to calculate the quantile curve on the original scales please see information please see my question here:

"[Quantile curves (strange results at 0.975 quantile)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/322638/quantile-curves-strange-results-at-0-975-quantile)"

Answer (score 1):

OK, I like the transformed data display. However, 1) Show the transforming equation. 2) You can use the original values on the transformed axes. For example, instead of showing the logarithm of age, show the ages that correspond to the those logarithms. This will make the x-axis show nonuniform spacing between ages, but they will be ages, not logarithms of ages, as logarithms of ages do not make sense to humans. Same type thing on the y-axis, whatever that is. 4) Put in the axis labels and units, cm, or whatever 5) Yes, fit the transformed data. You may be able to use just a linear regression for the transformed data, which is a lot more defensible, and less heuristic than splines. If you want, you can use [Theil regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theil%E2%80%93Sen_estimator) because ordinary least squares would be useless in this case.

Comment: great suggestion. I applied quantile regression(with 2 degrees and 3 degrees) on the transformed variable. I did not use spline, just parametric linear quantile regression. I used powerTransform function in R for data transformation. I used                                         
  "lam<-round(powerTransform(dataExample$y)$lambda,2)"
"dataExample$yy<-bcPower(dataExample$y,lam1)". Could you please see the new plots (6th and 7th plots/above) and let me know what you think.  (I will change the scale on the x and y based on your advice).

Comment: Also Regarding using " Theil regression", this is a very good suggestion but here I want to calculate the quantile curves (growth chart)  at 0.025 and 0.975 quantiles. It seems by using Theil regression, I can not have the quantile curves for these two quantiles. I check "mblm" function in R and this function just o fit linear models based on Theil-Sen single median. (Please correct me If I am wrong.)

Comment: Can you check if the coefficients have a partial probability of contributing to the model in order to choose between linear, 2nd and 3rd degree polynomials? I think maybe 2nd degree is good enough, using third degree may be a bit overfit. But, it would be nice to see linear as well. The equation for data transformation written in r-language is a bit abstract, what is it in normal language? You are close enough with quantile regression that Theil regression is likely unnecessary.

Comment: PS (+1) to you, but finish it up. Try histograms of transformed data as well.

Comment: Why is the y-axis data truncated? This is what makes the appearance of horizontal rows on the plots. If you can include more y-variable precision, that would be stronger.